# What kind of string representation is this?

Tags: php, hacklang

I'm running the following code and I get the following output. According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) it says it returns a binary string?

```
PHP\pack('H*', 'ab') //     "\253"
PHP\pack('H*', 'a')  //     "\240"
```

I can't for the life of me figure out 253 is 'ab'. `253` is `11111101` in binary which if you were to break out is

`1111` and `1101` which don't map to a or b?

What does "\253" represent?

Comment: U+00AB, character «‬, decimal 171, hex 0xAB, octal \253, binary 10101011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U+00AB, character `«‬`, decimal 171, hex 0xAB, octal \253, binary 10101011

Specifically: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder?encoding=numeric&bytes=0xc2%200xab

For any future issues: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?keywords=quotation